# what is the purpose of Offline mode in a web browser?

Tags: browser, offline-mode

What is actually the purpose of offline mode. does it somehow manages the caching system of the browser. or it just skips the host resolution part, dont know for what.
what probably the designer had in mind, when he developed the offline mode feature.

Comment: i asked this question in regard to my prev question. that i am not able to connect to my localhost from the browser when i am not connected to DSL network. but when i activate offline-mode i am. DNS shall resolve localhost to 127.0.0.1, and offline-mode does not, do anything which everyone has answered here as.

Comment: @Vivek: that's great, but what if we haven't ready your previous question? You should edit this question to include the link to your previous question. You might even include a summary of your previous question so we don't have to go back and read it. This isn't a discussion board - your previous question is nowhere in sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something that most of us wouldn't use very often, but it was useful in the past when we used dial-up modems (and especially for those of us who had time limited plans). You could connect to the internet, go to a website, quickly browse through everything you thought could be useful, disconnect, go to offline mode and then browse through the site as though you were connected (for everything was cached).

I didn't realise browsers still had them (I can't remember the last time I went to the File menu in Firefox though).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's something from the old days, where connections were mostly dial-up (read: slow, and not always connected), and browsers relied on caching material off-line, so if you're not connected, you'd see the cached version in an off-line mode.

I guess it still applies to countries that still don't have DSL everywhere.

Comment: +1, though caching is still highly important, especially on media heavy sites.

Answer (score 1):

You might use it to find out what happens to people who are using your web application if their internet connection is flaky or drops out. You can also use it if you're only interested in accessing local files, not websites.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't try to access the network, but instead fetches all content from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

in developed countries (asia especially), internet are rare and expensive (there are quota or time based) so offline is very good feature to have for them.

Sometimes you are out and you need to check something on web .. you can use that offline cache.

Comment: try undeveloped :-) And parts of Asia are among the most internet connected parts of the world

Comment: +1, East Asia and South East Asia are among the better part of the world with reliable Internet connection.

Comment: Try underdeveloped! Despite how it may appear, parts of the world without the Internet are not living in the Dark Ages.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it will became more used in the west these days as people with net-books and other ultra portable devices travel round lots? While wi-fi hot spots and 3g data connections are popular they are still not universal.

I know when I designed [my html/javascript open source chess clock](http://code.google.com/p/bobchess/), I deliberately designed it to work off-line very easily, so I could just download it onto my netbook and meet my chess friends in cafes without having to worry if the cafe had a good wifi signal or not.

Now, where's the "Blatant Plug" tag?

Answer (score 0):

It helps you to may be browse through a site fast & with a large cache size set , U go to offline mode & read the pages with your Time based Internet connection switched off.

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated by David Johnstone, I used to use the `Offline Mode` during dial-up days for reading articles/pages from cache when connection to the internet was disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

As my experience, normally offline servers are using while online servers are down or accessibility problem with our web server via internet, meanwhile we are using our offline server to get the informations. Then once the web server is up then we can synchronic the datas from offline server to online server.